# Change language of QGIS date/time settings

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, internationalization

In my QGIS installation 3.28.0 on Windows 10, dates are given in Swiss German dialect - like `Määntig` instead of `Montag` (as would be in standard German). This is annoying as no one in Switzerland ever uses our dialect in written form - it's just used in oral conversation. So I would like to change these settings. The QGIS User interface of the user profile I use is set to English.

However, I guess the settings depend on system language/localization/timezone settings where I defined german language settings for Switzerland - this makes quite a difference for using the keyboard etc. So I don't want to change Windows setting.

Is there a way to make these changes in QGIS only?

[image]

Comment: Schweizerdeutsch ist echt komisch... ^_^

Comment: Maybe like QGIS using суржик

Comment: That was funny >_< I did not know that you aware of such words )))

Comment: I can confirm that this information seems to rely on the system locale also on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: in Menu <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Options</kbd> > <kbd>General</kbd> tab, the entry for <kbd>Locale</kbd> was set to `Swiss German Switzerland (gsw_CH)`. When I change it to `German Switzerland (de_CH)`, I get the date in standard german.

So there is no need to make any changes in operating system settings, it's a QGIS setting that was set to this strange dialect version.

[image]