# Showing attribute field of date type with years in four digits in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, expression, date, format

#### The problem

In QGIS 3.34 Prizren, I have an attribute field of `date` type. Unfortunately, years are shown only with two digits: `23` instead of `2023`. As a historian, this is really bad as it could be also 1923, 1823 etc. I know that internally, QGIS uses the correct, 4-digit year values. But for reading the attribute table, I want to see the full numbers.

#### The Question

How can I show the date in a format with years with actual, four-digit numbers?

#### What I tried

I tried to use `format_date("date", 'dd. MM. yyyy')`, however, to no avail: in the preview, the desired format shows up, but when the field is created, all values are set to `NULL`. This applied to temporary scratch layers as well as to GeoPackage layers.

I also tried Menu <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Options</kbd> > <kbd>General</kbd>. I can change the `Locale` settings, but this does not affect the two-digit representation of the years.

---

*The issue seems to be a newer one, as a year before (must have been QGIS 3.28), with the same settings, [I had 4-digit numbers for the year](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/448535/88814) (compare with 2nd screenshot below).
Setting the locale to `"French France"` works (after restart of QGIS, using hint of @user30184). However, I would like to get 4-digit years in my locale `"German Switzerland"` as it was possible in older versions.*

*It is also strange that in my Windows 10 system Region settings, the year appears in 4 digits, even the "short version" (see screenshot, highlighted in red). It seems that in newer versions, QGIS does not respect system settings...*

[image]

#### A workaround

I could, of course, create a new field of type text/string and create a correctly looking date, but I try to avoid this as it is not very elegant and error-prone.

[image]

[image]

Comment: For me the Locale setting does have an effect but maybe you do not want to use for example "French France" locale. I do not know how to override the format for a selected locale.

Comment: `format_date` returns a string representation of a date, which means that you cannot enter it into a field of type "Date". That's why those are all NULL.

Comment: @user30184 indeed, changing locale to "French France" works (after restart of QGIS). However, as you suppose, I would like to get 4-digit years in my locale "German Switzerland"

Comment: What operating system are you using? If Windows, check the Short Date settings in your region/locale.

Comment: Hi Babel, I can reproduce the error. Since 3.34, it shows the timeformat in the official locale (https://www.localeplanet.com/icu/gsw-CH/index.html). If you use the C default (C), it uses the system default, but the long format. Perhaps there is a possibility you can override the format?

Comment: @TomBrennan I checked the Windows short date settings, thanks for the hint. However, there, it shows me 4 digit years (see screenshot in updated question), unlike in QGIS.

Comment: @eagleadmiral the link you provided does not work. Not exactly sure what you mean?

Comment: It's a bit strange. My system default short date format (Windows, en_AU) is d/MM/yyyy, QGIS shows Sample date: 21/11/23 under Settings->Options - General, but if I configure a date field in a layer, I get 21/11/2023. Not overly consistent!

Comment: Have you checked the field format under Layer Properties -> Attributes Form?

Comment: @TomBrennan Yes, it shows date and datetime: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFcZ0.png

Comment: I meant the Attributes Form, rather than the Fields. I can change the Date format - see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1Xrz.png

Comment: Remains the question how I can change this permanently, and not individually for each field/each layer separately.

Comment: @Babel I wanted to explain what the code in the brackets (de_CH) means. This refers to 'Unicode (ICU) Locale Formats', which is a database which stores all local information like the date-format, currency and language. QGIS will access the locale through the QLocale class (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.15/qlocale.html). Perhaps, the developer team from Qt or from QGIS has changed something, so that it now accesses the short datetime format from de_CH, and not the medium (see https://leap.hcldoc.com/help/topic/SSS28S_8.2.1/XFDL_Specification/i_xfdl_r_formats_de_CH.html).

Comment: @eagleadmiral Indeed, changing the locals to C default (C), I get four digit year numbers by default and not setting it manually. Would be good to post it as another answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under Layer Properties -> Attributes Form

[image]

You can select the field and control the Widget that it uses to display that field. In the case of Date fields, this includes controlling the format.

[image]

I'm not entirely sure why the default format in QGIS doesn't match the default system format, but at least there appears to be an avenue to control it.

Answer (score 5):

### Explanation:

First, let me clarify the meaning of the code in the brackets (de_CH):

This code refers to Unicode (ICU) Locale Formats, a database that stores local information such as date format, currency, and language. QGIS accesses this locale information through the QLocale class (see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.15/qlocale.html). Changing anything in your system settings will not affect the representation of the date format because you are overriding the default system settings.

It's possible that the development team, either from Qt or QGIS, has made changes resulting in the application now accessing the short datetime format from the de_CH locale instead of the medium format (as described in more detail at https://leap.hcldoc.com/help/topic/SSS28S_8.2.1/XFDL_Specification/i_xfdl_r_formats_de_CH.html).

### Approach

[image]
By choosing **C default (C)**, you opt for the default settings commonly used within programming environments on Windows. In @Babel's case, this corresponds to his requested 4 digit time format.

Another approach is stated in @Tom Brennan answer, but this cannot be set globally over all attribute tables. However, it's worth noting that Tom's answer is also valid and makes sense in certain applications.